# Allow PHP to read Apache log files

Tags: 18.04, apache2, filesystem, php

What is the best and most secure way, to change the owner/group/permissions of the apache error log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` such that it can be read by a php script i.e. in `/var/www/html/errors.php`?

I'm on ubuntu 18.4.
The rights of the log file are currently (untouched) set to 
`-rw-r-----  1 root adm`

Comment: You will need to add `www-data` (or whatever your Apache user is named) to `adm` with `sudo usermod -aG adm www-data`. This should allow you to read the files, so long as you call them by their specific name.

Comment: Make a root crontab that copy the error.log to /var/www/html and chown it www-data?

Comment: Thx both of you, the first seems a bit do widely, because I only want that specific one file to be read by exactly that script, not let the www-data user to read all adm files. Second one seems better but then delays the output by the refresh-rate.